# How to update web, smartphone apps in the same time

Tags: android, api, e-commerce, iso

I am new in this, so i am humbly asking to know how this works. Before giving me downgrade point, i m just new and already searched about this in internet and had no luck to find so i turned to you.

If i have an online store, which would also have Android and iOS app, so how would i update, edit and track my products (Selling and Inventory) at one place? Is there can be built an API that could control all of them at same time? Or it is not possible to do, or have other method to do such works?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create mobile API that pull data from the online store database. everything is updated on the online store will be shown in both mobile app and website at the same time as both of them is sharing the same database